# Get contents of msg file into string

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell to parse the contents of email messages that are saved to a local folder.

The code is as follows...

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\projtest\emails" -Filter *.msg |
ForEach-Object {
    $msg = ""
    $outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
    $msg = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($_.FullName)
    $msg | Select -ExpandProperty body 

    Write-Host $msg
}

$outlook.Quit()
```

For now, I just want to open the file, get the contents, and display it.

The issue I'm running into is that once the script is run, OUTLOOK.EXE does not close so I cannot run the script again on the same message.

Is there a better way to open Outlook e-mail messages, get the contents into a string in PowerShell, and close the Outlook process?

Answer (score 5):

Don't open and close Outlook, open it once, do all of your work, and then close it at the end of things.

```
$outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
Get-ChildItem "C:\projtest\emails" -Filter *.msg |
    ForEach-Object {
        $msg = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($_.FullName)
        $msg.body 
    }
$outlook.Quit()
```

**Edit:** Ok, you need to close your .msg files, not Outlook. Just add that to the `ForEach` loop:

```
$outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
Get-ChildItem "C:\projtest\emails" -Filter *.msg |
    ForEach-Object {
        $msg = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($_.FullName)
        $msg.body 
        $msg.Close()
    }
$outlook.Quit()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it makes no difference.

This message happens when trying to run the script again. OUTLOOK.EXE is still running in Processes.

`We can't open 'C:\projtest\emails\Project Creations 42517.msg'. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.`

Comment: Much appreciated! The idea is to be able to open/parse the message but not have to close Outlook in the process. I was hoping there would be some way to just close the .msg file without having to Kill the Outlook process.

Comment: Right, that's exactly what my last bit of code does. You don't have to close Outlook at all really. Remove that last line, and this should just connect to Outlook, and then open and parse messages, and close the messages as it goes.

Comment: unfortunately it actually kills the Outlook process running on the machine, which closes my Outlook client.

I posted the code over here to show what I did.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746981/parse-e-mail-message-contents-from-msg-file-in-powershell

Comment: If you have Outlook running most of the time, just drop the `.Quit()` line :-).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this into your script, (not sure if needed in loop) :-

```
$script:msg = ""
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).