# powershell Dump body text from outlook .msg file

Tags: powershell, outlook, msg

The following code outputs:

```
Body
----
Hi Joe,...
System.__ComObject
```

But I would like to output the entire message body.  There is a message within the message and I would like to iterate through all of them and just dump the text.  Note the commented line below that shows more information than I'm looking for.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\msgfolder\" -Filter *.msg | 
ForEach-Object{
    $outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
    $msg = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($_.FullName)
    #$msg | Select senderemailaddress,to,subject,Senton,body|ft -AutoSize
    $msg | Select body 
}
```

How do I capture both the body text to a string variable and pass the object to the next iteration in Powershell flow control?

Comment: You really should place the creation of the COM Object outside the loop... or at least close the outlook object inside the loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get contents of msg file into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618494/get-contents-of-msg-file-into-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
$mystring = $msg.body
Write-Host $mystring
```

Takes me through the entire body including each message in the thread.